# Xamarin Forms: Date picker not resizing full width on change

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have added a date picker in my Xamarin forms page. The issue I'm facing is on initial page load the size that the date picker occupies in the screen doesn't get resized on changing the date, if I select a date where text length is more than what was selected before.

Say for Example, If I had selected the date 21-May-2018 initially and If I change the date to 21-November-2018, now since the text length has increased the full text is not shown on the screen.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

XAML:

```
<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" Text="From" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                            <DatePicker Date="{Binding FromDateFilter}" TextColor="#777777" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" MaximumDate="{Binding ToDateFilter}">
                                <DatePicker.Format>dd-MMMM-yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                                <DatePicker.Effects>
                                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                                </DatePicker.Effects>
                            </DatePicker>
                        </StackLayout>
```

Initial Load: (Date Range -> From : 29-may-2017)

[image]

On change: (Date Range -> From: 29-november-2017)

[image]

Comment: Did you try FillAndExpand for horizontal options in the date picker?

Comment: I want the text to be aligned to right... With FillAndExpand, the text occupies the width on change. But is not aligned to right

Comment: Having similar problem and using Grid..

Comment: @J.J: Did you ever solve this?  The issue seems to still exist in Xamarin 5...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I can't remember, probably not (I was just experimenting with Xamarin). I don't have android tools installed right now, but the last version of code I had on Git looks like `<DatePicker Format="d" VerticalOptions="Center" Date="{Binding SelectedItem.AddedDate}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>`

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still waiting for a fix even on version `Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012`, here's a workaround:

Extend `Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker` and call `InvalidateMeasure` whenever the date changes:

```
public class FixedDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public FixedDatePicker()
    {
        DateSelected += FixedDatePicker_DateSelected;
    }

    private void FixedDatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateMeasure();
    }
}
```

Use this extended class instead of the default in your XAML.

I hope that the Xamarin team fixes this bug soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
   <StackLayout 
      Orientation="Horizontal" 
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"> 
      put your DatePicker inside this.                       
   </StackLayout>
```

and give WidthRequest to your DatePicker or else batter to use Grid instead StackLayout

Comment: Not able to achieve this even with Grid to align the text to right